# Prevent Other DMLS from being rollbacked because of error throen by another DML

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a anonymous block in PL/SQL:

```
begin
dml1
dml2
dml3
end;
/
```

I do not want the `dml1` and `dml3` from being rolled back if `DML2` throws an error. I cannot use `DBMS_ERRLOG` and pragma autonous_transaction. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

Simply handle any exception DML2 throws:

```
begin
  dml1;

  begin
    dml2;
  exception
    when others then
      null; -- or log, or report error, or whatever
  end;

  dml3;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is exception handling.

```
begin
  begin 
    dml1
  exception
    when others then null; --- generally not indicated
     /*there should be an error handling section, or, at leasr
      an error logging procedure*/
  end;
  begin
    dml2
  exception
    when others then null; 
  end;

    dml3     
end;
```

RTM on exception handling and see what exceptions may occur in your data processing and decide how they are to be handled based on the business requirements.